# Fancytree can't use ext-edit with ext-dnd?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-draggable, fancytree

jQuery UI 1.11 + Fancytree 2.3.0

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  extensions: ["edit", "dnd"],
  edit{ ... },
  dnd{ ... },
  ...
});
```

[DnD]

- Already effective.

[Edit]

- [F2] - ignore.
- [Shift+Click] - effective.

---

Couldn't F2 key when use dnd extension. Why sabotage the "F2" ?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery UI 1.11 - Draggable]

```
var mouse = $.widget("ui.mouse", {
  ...
  _mouseDown: function(event) {
    ...
    this.document
      .bind( "mousemove." + this.widgetName, this._mouseMoveDelegate )
      .bind( "mouseup." + this.widgetName, this._mouseUpDelegate );

    event.preventDefault();

    mouseHandled = true;
    return true;
},
```

Fancytree(ul.fancytree-container) missing focus when blocking event.preventDefault().

If you can stubborn focusing. try this code.

```
$("#tree").fancytree({
  extensions: ["edit", "dnd"],
  edit{ ... },  
  dnd{ ... },
  click: function(event, data){
    data.tree.$container.focus();
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: negative. code-comment says 'draggable cancels mousedown' but nothing has worked for me. :S

Comment: maybe dnd.focusOnClick have a other problem. I make issue: https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/300

Comment: This solution worked for me. If it's an option for you, you can resort to using jQuery UI 1.10.4. It also worked, but I'd rather use a newer version of jQuery UI.